# CreatingSite Collection Programtically - SharePoint Web site has exceeded the storage quota limit

Tags: quota

While creating site collection programtically i am getting following message :  Your changes could not be saved because this SharePoint Web site has exceeded the storage quota limit. You must save your work to another location. Contact your administrator to change the quota limits for the Web site.

So on which site the quota size should be increased ?

Answer (score 2):

1. On the Central Administration home page, click Application Management.
2. On the Application Management page, in the Site Collections section, click Configure quotas and locks. Select the site collection required to change the quota and then set quoata size.

For more details on changing the quota [visit this msdn post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263480.aspx#BKMK_Updatequotatemplateforsite).